# What are the properties of square-matrix algebra with this equivalence class?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hypercomplex-numbers

Consider the set of all square matrices with the following equivalence class:

$\mathbf{A}\sim\mathbf{A}\otimes\mathbf{I}_n$,

for each $n$, where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product and $\mathbf{I}_n$ is identity matrix of order $n$.

For instance, the following matrices are considered equivalent:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This rule allows to make dot product of any two square matrices, as well as to rise a matrix to matrix power irrespective of their orders.

I wonder, what properties the resulting infinite-dimensional vector space has? Obviously it includes subsets isomorphic to all possible hypercomplex systems, including quaternions, split-quaternions, tessarines, grassman numbers, triplex numbers, $\mathbb{R}^n$, hyperbolic numbers, Clifford algebras and all possible their combinations, allowing to make arithmetic operations on hypercomplex numbers from different systems and mix them in one expression.

But what would be the overall algebraic outlook of this set?

Below is the code for Mathematica system that realises this algebra:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
$PrePrint =.; FormatValues@Matrix = {};
Hold[MakeBoxes[Matrix[a_], StandardForm] ^:= 
    Block[{Internal`$ConvertForms = {}}, 
     TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[MatrixForm@a][[1, 1, 3]]}, "Matrix", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{style@"(", "\[NoBreak]", #, 
           "\[NoBreak]", style@")"} &)]]] /. 
  style[string_] -> StyleBox[string, FontColor -> Red] // ReleaseHold
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Dot[A_?SquareMatrixQ, B_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
  Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
      IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
     KroneckerProduct[B, 
      IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]] /; 
   Length[A] != Length[B];
Protect[Dot];
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_] := 
  Dot[Matrix[x], y];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[y_, Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Dot[y, Matrix[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Matrix[y] . Log[Matrix[x]]];
Matrix /: Log[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
 Log[Matrix[x]] . Log[Matrix[y]]^-1
Matrix /: Im[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Im[x]]
Matrix /: Re[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Re[x]]
Matrix /: Arg[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := Matrix[Arg[x]]
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[A_?SquareMatrixQ], Matrix[B_?SquareMatrixQ]] := 
 Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
   KroneckerProduct[B, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]]

$Post2 = 
  FullSimplify[# /. 
     f_[args1___?NumericQ, Matrix[mat_], args2___?NumericQ] :> 
      Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]]] &;
$Post = Nest[$Post2, #, 3] /. Dot -> NonCommutativeMultiply &;
```

Test:

```
Matrix[{
   {1, 3},
   {0, 2}
  }]^Matrix[{
   {1, 0, 1},
   {1, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 2}
  }]
```

Comment: "...as well as raise a matrix to matrix power irrespective of their orders" - how? We don't start out being able to raise a matrix to the power of another matrix for any order, so I don't see how the equivalence relation would change things.

Comment: @MishaLavrov see the code, the rules are there. Basically, $A^B=\exp(B \cdot \ln A)$. Since we can multiply matrices of any orders, we can rise a matrix to matrix as well.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez okay, I've explained without the code.

Comment: @Anixx I don't see how this allows us to take a product of matrices of non-matching order. For example, what would the result of
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4} \cdot \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9}
$$
be?

Comment: @BenGrossmann  $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 8 & 2 & 10 & 3 & 12 \\
 14 & 1 & 16 & 2 & 18 & 3 \\
 4 & 14 & 5 & 16 & 6 & 18 \\
 3 & 16 & 6 & 20 & 9 & 24 \\
 28 & 3 & 32 & 6 & 36 & 9 \\
 12 & 28 & 15 & 32 & 18 & 36 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ You can try the code yourself (Wolfram cloud is free to use on Android devices). The order of the result is the least common multiple of the orders of the original matrices.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  $$\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4} \cdot \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 6 \\
 7 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Anixx Makes sense, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Now [crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/436567/19965). In general one should not crosspost without mentioning you are doing so.